# Being wrapped by a directive, how can I access its scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I access the directive's isolate scope in the directive's body? My DOM looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">    
    <directive>
        <p>boolProperty: {{boolProperty|json}}</p>
    </directive>
</div>
```

The `boolProperty` is assigned inside the directive's `link` function:

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("directive", function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope) {
            $scope.boolProperty = true;
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is, the child `<p>` inside the directive binds to the directive's **parent** scope, not the directive's isolated scope. How can I overcome this?

[**Click here for jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/akashivskyy/Y9g4q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about two things:

1. By default AngularJS uses attrubute restriction, so in your case in directive definition you should specify `restrict: "E"`
2. You should use child scope, but not isolated. So set `scope: true` to inherit from parent view scope.

See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y9g4q/1/.

Good luck.

Comment: And if I create a child scope, how can I "transfer" something like `scope { myAction: "&" }`?

Comment: you can directly get it in link function from attributes http://jsfiddle.net/Y9g4q/3/

Comment: What about something like `my-action="action()"`? How can I call the specified function (which apparently is defined in the parent scope)? Or am I up to something far too complicated? :D

Comment: I'm not sure am I right, you can evaluate attribute in context of scope, please see another fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y9g4q/5/

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of problems in your code.

1. The default restrict option is `A` for attribute so anyways your directive will not be compiled because you are using it as an element. Use `restrict: 'E'` to make it work.
2. As per the documentation, the scope of the transcluded element is not a child scope of the directive but a sibling one. So `boolProperty` will always be undefined or empty. So you have to go up the scope level and find the proper sibling.

   ```
   <div ng-app="app">
      <directive>
       <p>boolProperty: {{$parent.$$childHead.boolProperty}}</p>
       </directive>
   </div>
   ```

and need to use transclusion in the directive as:

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("directive", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.boolProperty = true;
        }
    };
});
```

However, this approach is not advisable and break later If you add a new controller before the directive because transcluded scope becomes 2nd sibling unlike 1st as before.

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="OneCtrl"></div>
    <directive>
        <p>boolProperty: {{$parent.$$childHead.boolProperty || $parent.$$childHead.$$nextSibling.boolProperty}}</p>
    </directive>
</div>
```

Here is the <kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9g4q/4/)</kbd>. The approach I mentioned is not ideal so use at your own risk. The @CodeHater' s answer is the one you should go with. I just wanted to explain why it did not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

`As the name suggests, the isolate scope of the directive isolates everything except models that you've explicitly added to the scope: {} hash object. This is helpful when building reusable components because it prevents a component from changing your model state except for the models that you explicitly pass in.`

It seems you would need to explicitly add `boolProperty` to `scope`.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">    
    <directive bool="boolProperty">
        <p>boolProperty: {{boolProperty|json}}</p>
    </directive>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.boolProperty = false;
}).directive("directive", function() {
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        scope: {boolProperty:'=bool'},
        link: function($scope) {
            $scope.boolProperty = "i'm a boolean property";
        }
    };
});
```

Here's updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9g4q/2/).