# Directive with isolated scope and added properties, not available to inner directives

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to have a directive with an isolated scope, and to set properties to this scope from within the directive. That is to create some environment variables, which would be displayed by other directives inside it, like so:

HTML:

```
<div environment>          <!-- this directive set properties to the scope it creates-->
  {{ env.value }}                  <!-- which would be available -->
  <div display1 data="env"></div>  <!-- to be displayed by other directives (graphs, -->
  <div display2 data="env"></div>  <!-- charts...) -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("test", [])
  .directive("environment", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.env = {
          value: "property set from inside the directive"
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .directive("display1", function() {
    return  {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^environment'
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elt, attr, envController) {

        scope.$watch('data', function(oldV, newV) {
          console.log("display data");
        });

      }
    };
  })
  .directive("display2", function() {
    return {/* ... */};
  });
```

But it doesn't work. Here is [a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lLZRiUnFNmRi4NNrHO8y).
If I remove the isolation, it works ok though. What do I do wrong ? Is it a problem of transclusion ? It seems to work if I use a template in the 'environment' directive, but this is not what I want.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** I see this same problem answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24015987/2269705). The proposed solution would be to use a controller instead of a directive. The reason I wanted to use a directive is the possibility to use 'require' in the inner directives, thing that can't be done with ngController I think.

Comment: A similar question was just asked, and the answers to it should be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015300/being-wrapped-by-a-directive-how-can-i-access-its-scope

Comment: @MarcKline: thanks, I just saw (although I spent some time searching :-\ ). I edited my post in that way.

Comment: I didn't see the controllers suggestion, but maybe I should have specifically endorsed [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015300/being-wrapped-by-a-directive-how-can-i-access-its-scope#answer-24015987). Here's a fork of your Plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xjp5pPgsJo4sKpJIrwnw?p=preview

Comment: @MarcKline: I didn't know this was possible without the surrounding ngController in the answer you're pointing. So it means the isolate scope applies already in the tag calling the directive... Looks like a hack, but it does the job.

Comment: I think the controller was setup in the example just to show that the value was coming from the directive's scope, not the controller's.

Answer (score 0):

By introducing external templates, I managed to find a working solution to your problem. 
I'm quite certain the way you have it set up has worked at some point but I can't be certain about when. The last time I built a directive **not** reliant on an external markup file, I don't even know.

In any case, the following should work, if you are willing to introduce separate templates for your directives:

```
app.directive('environment', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'env.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.env = {
              value: "property set from inside the directive"
            };
        }
    };
});

app.directive('display1', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'display1.html',
        replace: false,
        link: function(scope) {
            // console.log(scope.data);
        }
    };
});
```

And then for your markup (these wouldn't sit in `<script>` tags realistically, you would more than likely have an external template but this is simply taken from the fiddle I set up).

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="display1.html">
    <span>Display1 is: {{data}}</span>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="env.html">
    <div>
        <h1>env.value is: {{env.value}}</h1>
        <span display1 data="env.value"></span>        
    </div>
</script>

<div>
    <div environment></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/5421/

**Edit**: After reading that you do **not** want to use templates (should've done that first..), here's another solution to get it working. Unfortunately, the only one you can go with (aside from a few others, link coming below) and in my opinion it is not a good looking one...

```
app.directive('environment', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: function (element, attrs) {
          return element.html();
        },
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
          scope.env = {
            value: "property set from inside the directive"
          };
        }
    };
});
```

And the markup:

```
<div environment> {{env.value}} </div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7K6KK/1/

Say what you will about it, but it does do the trick.

[Here's a thread off of the Angular Github Repo](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5112), outlining your issue and why it is *not* 'supported'.

Answer (score -1):

I did a small edit to your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gCgoo63QkWUaCACcdA40?p=preview)
When you create a variable on scope of directive other directives can access it two ways (presented in plunker) either directly or by two-way data binding

#### HTML:

```
<body ng-app="test">
  <div environment>
    {{ env.value }}
    <div display1 data="env"></div>
    <div display2 data="env"></div>
  </div>
</body>
  <input type="text" ng-model="env.value"> #added to show two-way data binding work
  <div display1 info="env"></div> #changed name of attribute where variable is passed, it's then displayed inside directive template
  <div display2>{{env.value}}</div> #env.value comes from environment directive not from display2
</div>
```

#### JS

```
angular.module("test", [])
  .directive("environment", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true, #changed from {} to true, each environment directive will have isolated scope
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.env = {
          value: "property set from inside the directive"
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .directive("display1", function() {
    return  {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<span ng-bind="info.value"></span>', #added template for directive which uses passed variable, NOTE: dot in ng-bind, if you try a two-way databinding and you don't have a dot you are doing something wrong (Misko Hevry words)
      scope: {
        info: '=' #set two-way data binding for variable from environment directive passed in 'info' attribute
      }, #removed unnecessary watch for variable
    };
  })
  .directive("display2", function() {
    return {/* ... */};
  });
```

Comment: OP says `If I remove the isolation, it works ok though.` which indicates that they tried `scope: true` on the element but that it wasn't a solution that works for them.